# Write tifs as a datacube

Tags: python, pandas, dask, ram, python-xarray

I have a folder of `.tif` files, I want to merge them in a datacube. By *datacube* I mean a `netcdf` file, or `zarr` files. The goal is that if I open this datacube in Python, I can access a 3D array representing the stack of `tif` files.

**Context:** The files never overlap spatially, but stitched together they cover one big area. They are named after a date: some tifs have the same date (in which case they are merged with `xr.concat(dim='x')`).

**Goal:** I want to combine all these tifs in one dataset and save this dataset. I want to do that with `dask` so I don't encounter memory issues.

**Questions:**

- How to concatenate and save datasets as zarr or netcdf with `dask` so we don't overload memory ?

**Code example:**

```
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

# List of dates, 3 files share the same date
list_dates = [
    pd.Timestamp('2014-10-08 00:00:00'),
    pd.Timestamp('2014-10-13 00:00:00'),
    pd.Timestamp('2014-10-15 00:00:00'),
    pd.Timestamp('2014-10-15 00:00:00'),
    pd.Timestamp('2014-10-15 00:00:00')
]

# In the list of files, the last 3 files have the same date
list_files = [
    '2014-10-08_0.tif',
    '2014-10-13_0.tif',
    '2014-10-15_0.tif',
    '2014-10-15_1.tif', 
    '2014-10-15_2.tif'
] 

# Count how many times each date appears 
date_counts = Counter(list_dates)

# Initialize the list hosting the DataArrays
data_arrays = []
# Initialize the counter
i = 0

# Loop that appends the DataArrays and concatenates them if the files have the same date
while i < len(list_files):
    
    # If the date is unique, append the DataArrays list
    if date_counts[list_dates[i]] == 1:
    # Open the file as a dataarray (index [0] because it is opened as a 3D array even though it is 2D)
    data_array = xr.open_dataarray(list_files[i][0])
    # Add the timestamp as a dimension
        data_array = data_array.expand_dims({'time': [list_dates[i]]})
        data_arrays.append(data_array)
        i += 1 # Update the iterator
        
    # If the date has multiple occurrences, concatenate spatially the files sharing the same date
    else:
        # Open all the files with the same date as dataarrays and store them in a temporary list
        ds_temp = xr.concat([xr.open_dataarray(list_files[j])[0] for j in range(i, i + date_counts[list_dates[i]])], dim='x')
        # Add a time dimension
        ds_temp = ds_temp.expand_dims({'time': [list_dates[i]]})
        data_arrays.append(ds_temp)
        i += date_counts[list_dates[i]] # Update the iterator by the amount of files that were used in the concatenation

# Concatenate all the DataArrays in the final list along the 'time' dimension
final_dataset = xr.concat(data_arrays, dim='time')

# Print the final dataset
print(final_dataset)
```

Comment: What shape do you expect the output of your example to have? Would there be unfilled tiles in the overall cube?

Comment: There would never be a completely empty tile, if there is one then it will have at least 1 pixel of value. But the tiles might be mostly empty, yes.
I know it's not efficient in terms of memory management, but that's the only way I can think of to then apply some matrix analysis on this dataset (eigen decomposition, SVD, etc..)

Comment: The values of `x` (spatial coordinate) are automatically determined from each input TIFF file?

Comment: Yes. Each TIFF file will be loaded as an xarray dataset with `x` and `y` automatically determined. Each TIFF shares the same coordinates system so they `x` and `y` allow to locate them to each other in space

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how to get an xarray to dynamically resize or to open a new one with no data so that you can fill it - that's effectively what you are doing. I suspect it is totally possible.

However, here are two ways to achieve what you are doing.

- *kerchunk* should allow you to make a global dataset view of all your files. Either each file is a single chunk, or you address the internal chunking scheme of the files (works well with CoGs, see also [tiffile](https://github.com/cgohlke/tifffile/)). In this case, you don't need to copy the data at all, but could decide to convert to zarr as a separate step. Figuring this path out is somewhat involved.
- *zarr* directly allows you to make arrays of any shape and fill them. In your current workflow, you would need to determine the expected data shape

.

```
g = zarr.open_group("mydir", mode="w")
time = g.create_dataset("time", data=list_dates, dtype="M8[ms]")
x = g.create_dataset("x", data=range-of-x)
y = g.create_dataset("y", data=range-of-x)
data = g.create_dataset("data", dtype="float64", shape=(5, <y size> , <concatenated x size>), chunks=(1, <ysize>, <single x size>)
```

To make is all loadable by xarray, you need "_ARRAY_DIMENSIONS" in the .attrs of each array

```
time.attrs["_ARRAY_DIMENSIONS"] = ["time"]
x.attrs["_ARRAY_DIMENSIONS"] = ["x"]
y.attrs["_ARRAY_DIMENSIONS"] = ["y"]
data.attrs["_ARRAY_DIMENSIONS"] = ["time", "y", "x"]
```

And then fill the data

```
for file...
    chunk = load(..) # with xarray, probably
    data[timepoint, yslice, xslice] = chunk
```